# Cassandra wrong save time value

Tags: postgresql, express, cassandra

i'm done created code in express.js for save data into postgres and cassandra, code include for get time from server :

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "-" 
                + currentdate.getDate() + " "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

i use variable `datetime` for save data into postgres and cassandra, in postgres data `datetime` is `2015-09-17 09:39:27` but in cassandra is `2015-09-17 02:39:27+0000` there is different in time value

time in postgres is correct

how can i fix this ?

thx

Comment: Seems like a timezone difference? The Cassandra timestamp appears to be in UTC (+0000) but what is the timezone of the Postgres timestamp?

Comment: @Peter how can i change timezone in cassandra ?